# react native can not push a screen from 'screen modal'

Tags: react-native, navigation, modalviewcontroller

i have a modal screen like below:

```
 <Stack.Screen name="ForwardChatContent" component={ForwardChatContentScreen}
                            options={{
                              presentation: 'modal',
                            }} />
```

[image]

I want to push a screen from this screen, for example i have other screen like below:

```
<Stack.Screen name="ForwardChatToUser" component={ForwardChatToUserScreen}
```

But when using navigate, it's does not show new screen, can someone help? Thanks

Update, i changed ForwardChatContent and ForwardChatToUser into stack navigator like this:

```
const forwardStack = () => {
    return <Stack.Navigator>
      <>
        <Stack.Screen name="ForwardChatContent" component={ForwardChatContentScreen}
          options={{
            presentation: 'modal',
          }} />
        <Stack.Screen name="ForwardChatToUser" component={ForwardChatToUserScreen}
          options={{
            // presentation: 'modal',
          }} />
      </>
    </Stack.Navigator>
  }
```

when navigate im using this code:

```
RootNavigation.navigate('ForwardChat', {message : props.currentMessage})
```

But in ForwardChatContent i got error ***ERROR  TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'route.params.message')****
Because Im using this code to get message :

```
 const message = route.params.message
```

Can u provide some way to get the params, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because when you open a screen as Modal, it is treated as a separate set out of your existing Navigation Stack, it expects a Modal to be a NavigationStack, not just a Screen.

In your case, `ForwardChatContentScreen` is just a simple <Stack.Screen> it doesn't have a navigation stack.

Change it to NavigationStack from Screen it will work and open the NavigationStack as Modal having your screen as root, then it will work.

Check [demo here](https://snack.expo.dev/@vedexpo/brave-carrot)

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I know the question it's old, but I had myself dealt with this problem right now, as a solution I found calling pop before navigate:

```
RootNavigation.pop();    
RootNavigation.navigate('ForwardChat', {message : props.currentMessage})
```

Posting this as an alternative solution to the one provided by @iphonic